# Vitest - Module not found error getting while running test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, vitest

I am stuck in the problem where i was writing test and they are getting successful in vitest and after some time i got error while running the command

```
npm run test filename
```

and i don't have any idea about it and i tried installing and uninstalling vitest but nothing work

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sharm\Documents\github\analysistool-react\node_modules\vitest\node_modules\magic-string\dist\magic-string.es.mjs' imported from C:\Users\sharm\Documents\github\analysistool-react\node_modules\vitest\dist\cli.js
Did you mean to import magic-string/dist/magic-string.cjs.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

any help will be great

Comment: have you fixed this or it still unresolved?